regsvr32: The module may not compatible with the version of Windows that you're running
I built a C++ DLL on Windows 11 and verified it works but when I try to install it on a Windows 10 machine I am getting this error:
The module ""%1"" may not compatible with the version of Windows that you're running. Check if the module is compatible with an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of regsvr32.exe

I verified using dumpbin /headers that the DLL is indeed 64 bit.
How can I further debug and fix this? The OS I am running is of course 64 bit on a 64 bit processor. I also checked I am running 64 bit version of regsvr32.exe.

Found the issue with ProcMon. An incorrect DLL was being loaded:
"8:31:05.3917663 AM","regsvr32.exe","13892","Load Image","C:\Windows\System32\onnxruntime.dll","SUCCESS","Image Base: 0x7ffba1800000, Image Size: 0x1000"

More info over here if it helps someone.
